# Spring individual context not inheriting root context

Tags: spring-mvc

I have two context xml resides in WEB-INF folder; `applicationContext.xml` and `app-servlet.xml`. I declare this in app-servlet.xml

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.training.hibernate.controller"/>`

and this in applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.training.hibernate.services"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.training.hibernate.dao"/>
```

I got this error

```
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
```

If I move the component scanning of services and dao in app-servlet.xml, I got no error. I assume the app-servlet.xml is not inheriting the applicationContext.xml

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
  <display-name>Spring Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please share your web.xml entries for loading your spring xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some direction I can help you with to clarify different contexts. There are two main contexts usually in a Spring based web app :

1. Application Context : The context which contains the beans like services,dao etc.

   ```
    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
           classpath:spring-config/applicationContext.xml
       </param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
      </listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```
2. And then there is dispatcher servlet's context. This contains web specific beans . This context has access to beans defined via ContextLoaderListener above.

   `<servlet>
         <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
         </servlet-class>
         <init-param>
               <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
               <param-value>
                   classpath:spring-config/app-servlet.xml
               </param-value>
           </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>`

Please verify, you have got this right.

Comment: please see my web.xml. I'm not using ContextLoaderListener.

Comment: ok. It seems your applicationContext.xml is not loaded in your application at all, as you are using default config locations. Please either follow the approach I mentioned . Or have an '<import resource="classpath:..pathTo/applicationContext.xml"/> inside your app-servlet.xml.

Comment: Thanks. Ill try the import one.